# How to link to another page in javascript?

Tags: javascript

So I am having trouble linking from one page to another in JavaScript. I have the following code.

I am trying to call when users click submit. Below is the form I want users to fill out. I am trying to get to feed.html when users click submit.

```js
function login(){
    window.location="feed.html";
}
```

```html
<form>
    <p>Username</p>
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter Username" value="">
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Enter Password">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Login" onClick="login()">
    <a href="#">Lost your password?</a><br>
    <a href="#">Don't have an account?</a>
</form>
```

So I thought it would simply call the function and go to the feed page after clicking submit, but instead it does nothing. Does anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: The code navigates as is. But, it won't send the form data anywhere. Instead set your form tag to be `<form action="feed.html" method="get">`. Then you don't need the `login` function at all. Also, your `input` elements must have a value for `name` otherwise they won't transmit their data.

Comment: 1. use `action="/feed.html"` attribute in the form.
 or
2. use `event.preventDefault();` in your function.

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)  … and is entirely pointless if it just repeats information from the label.

Comment: I know I can just use action but I want to know how to do it using JavaScript if possible

Answer (score 3):

Submitting a form navigates to the page that is the response to the form submission.

Assigning a URL to `location` navigates to that URL.

So:

1. Your JavaScript runs
2. The JS starts navigation to `feed.html`
3. The form submits
4. The form navigates to the current URL (since you didn't specify an `action`) instead.

The navigation in step 4 replaces the navigation in step 2.

---

Your options:

- Don't use a submit button
- Call `preventDefault` to prevent the default action of clicking on a submit button
- Set an `action` instead of using JavaScript

---

The last of these choices is probably the sensible one. You have what appears to be a login form. Handling all the authentication logic that decides if the user can login or not inside the browser (which is under the control of the **user**) instead of on the server is a huge no-no.

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe use the "action" attribute on your form tag.

```
<form action="feed.html">
  ...
</form>
```

This will submit your form and redirect to feed.html.